# How to insert table rows in a foreach loop in a blade.php file in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, html, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have created a view page where I am getting an Eloquent variable from my controller. That variable points to the elements in a table. This is my current code.

```
  <table border="0px">
    <tr>
    @foreach ($teacher as $value) 
        <?php    
            $tid = $value->teacherID;
        ?>

        <tr>
            <td> <a href="info/{{ $tid }}"> {{ $value['teacher_name'] }} </a></td>
            <td>{{ $value['course_name'] }}</td>
        </tr>
        <hr>

    @endforeach
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am getting an unexpected output with this code. I am getting number of blank spaces in the beginning and then my table(mysql) elements. Please help me resolve the issue guys. 
Thanks,
Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel follow this approach:

Controller function:

```
myFunction()
{
    $myData = array('1' => 'One', '2' => 'Two');    // sample data. You can get this data from DB
    return view('myView', array('data' => $myData));
}
```

`myView.blade.php`:

Here you can use the $data array like:

```
{{ $data['1'] }}
{{ $data['2'] }}
```

Now track your methods accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Mayank.                                      returnView::make('viewb')->with('teacher', $teacher); //My controller stuff

Comment: Can I not continue with the same logic?

Comment: Yes you can return view('myView', array('data' => $myData)); and returnView::make('viewb')->with('teacher', $teacher); is same.

Comment: Ok, Then you mean to say I need to use index numbers while retrieving it. But what if new entries are kept on adding onto my table. Acc to you, I should retrieve it by indices which would be a static way. Right?

Comment: You can use foreach also. Its just a demo example bro

Comment: Ok. Thanks for giving your precious time. I got my issue resolved.

Comment: I got the answer from @MohamedNizar comment, not answer! Its a request to stackoverflow to please allow ticking the comments as answers as well :-p :-D

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getTeachers(){
    $teachers = Teachers::all();
    return('teachers',compact('teachers'));
}
```

in blade file you can read properties in

```
 @foreach ($teacher as $value) 
    if($value != '' || $value != null)
        ID:{{$value->teacherID}}
 @endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @Mohammed. I am done with the functionality part, but while viewing I get some empty rows, which I do not want. Please help me out.

Comment: @AvinashJaiswal check whether the value exist or not in view!or you may have empty records in your DB.

Comment: Right! Cheers @MohamedNizar

Comment: Did you find solution from my answer?

Comment: Yes got it. Thanks once again!